# How to apply the multiple attribute to the selectric dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectric

I have used `selectric` plugin for the `dropdown`. I have added the multiple attribute in the select tag but it is not working as they have show on the following 
link of the index page of the selectric plugin : http://selectric.js.org/

This is what I have tried :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selectric.css"  />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.selectric.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">Select Numbers</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
 <script>
$('select').selectric();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Note:** `<script src="jquery.selectric.min.js"></script>` should be enough, no need to add the library twice

Comment: still not working even if i remove the extra library

Comment: @Ninad are you getting any errors on developer console?

Comment: Try adding your `$('select').selectric()` _after_ the select element, or alternatively wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: still not working i have added the  $('select').selectric() after the select element

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tedekiqequ/edit?html,output) you can find your example working right.
I think you've included in your project bad files (js or css ones).